# CSS Fade effecting other elements

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm using javascript and CSS to fade an image behind a menu, but the menu should stay visible. For some reason the menu fades also. It shouldn't since I'm not targeting those elements. [Here is an example.](http://m4tt1mus.github.io/example/example.html)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to directly include code for a [**minimal**, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your link, if you add a `z-index` value of 1 or greater to your `menu` class, then the menubar will not fade.

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
  <div class="menu" style="z-index: 1;">
    <span><a href="#schedule">Schedule</a></span>
    <span class="spacer">|</span>
    <span><a href="#sponsors">Sponsors</a></span>
    <span class="spacer">|</span>
    <span><a href="#bio">Bio</a></span><a name="bio"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```